# Inserting lots of values (with FK's) into database using LiquiBase and Spring

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, liquibase

I'm trying to add a lot of records (currently located in an Excel file) into my DB using Liquibase (so that I know how to do it for future DB changes)

My idea was to read the excel file using Java, and then fill the ChangeLogParameters from my Spring initialization class like this:

```
SpringLiquibase liqui = new SpringLiquibase();
liqui.setBeanName("liquibaseBean");
liqui.setDataSource(dataSource());
liqui.setChangeLog("classpath:changelog.xml");

HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
values.put("line1col1", ExcelValue1);
values.put("line1col2", ExcelValue2);
values.put("line1col3", ExcelValue3);
values.put("line2col1", ExcelValue4);
values.put("line2col2", ExcelValue5);
values.put("line2col3", ExcelValue6);
...
liqui.setChangeLogParameters(values);
```

The problem with this approach is that my changelog.xml would be very strange (and non productive)

```
<changeSet author="gcardoso" id="2012082707">
    <insert tableName="t_user">
        <column name="login" value="${ExcelValue1}"/>
        <column name="name" value="${ExcelValue2}}"/>
        <column name="password" value="${ExcelValue3}"/>
    </insert>
    <insert tableName="t_user">
        <column name="login" value="${ExcelValue4}"/>
        <column name="name" value="${ExcelValue5}}"/>
        <column name="password" value="${ExcelValue6}"/>
    </insert>
    ...
</changeSet>
```

Is there any way that I could do something like this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> values = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
values.put("col1", Column1);
values.put("col2", Column2);
values.put("col3", Column3);
liqui.setChangeLogParameters(values);

<changeSet author="gcardoso" id="2012082707">
    <insert tableName="t_user">
        <column name="login" value="${Column1}"/>
        <column name="name" value="${Column2}}"/>
        <column name="password" value="${Column3}"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

Or is there any other way?

**EDIT :**
My current option is to convert the Excel into a CSV file and import the data using

```
<changeSet author="gcardoso" id="InitialImport2" runOnChange="true">

    <loadData tableName="T_ENTITY" file="com/exictos/dbUpdate/entity.csv">
        <column header="SHORTNAME" name="SHORTNAME" />
        <column header="DESCRIPTION" name="DESCRIPTION" />
    </loadData>


    <loadData tableName="T_CLIENT" file="com/exictos/dbUpdate/client.csv">
        <column header="fdbhdf" name="ENTITYID" defaultValueComputed="(SELECT ID FROM T_ENTITY WHERE SHORTNAME = ENTITY_REFERENCE"/>
        <column header="DESCRIPTION" name="DESCRIPTION" />
    </loadData>


</changeSet>
```

with these CSV files:

entity.csv

```
SHORTNAME,DESCRIPTION
nome1,descricao1
nome2,descricao2
```

client.csv

```
DESCRIPTION,ENTITY_REFERENCE
descricaoCliente1,nome1
descricaoCliente2,nome2
```

But I get this error:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL INSERT INTO `T_CLIENT` (`DESCRIPTION`, `ENTITY_REFERENCE`) VALUES ('descricaoCliente1', 'nome1'): Unknown column 'ENTITY_REFERENCE' in 'field list'
```

If I change the header of my client.csv to  DESCRIPTION,ENTITYID I get this error:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL INSERT INTO `T_CLIENT` (`DESCRIPTION`, `ENTITYID`) VALUES ('descricaoCliente1', 'nome1'): Incorrect integer value: 'nome1' for column 'entityid' at row 1
```

I any of these cases, it looks like defaultValueComputed doesn't work in the same way as valueComputed in the following example

```
<changeSet author="gcardoso" id="InitialImport1">

    <insert tableName="T_ENTITY">
        <column name="SHORTNAME">nome1</column>
        <column name="DESCRIPTION">descricao1</column>
    </insert>

    <insert tableName="T_CLIENT">
        <column name="ENTITYID" valueComputed="(SELECT ID FROM T_ENTITY WHERE SHORTNAME = 'nome1')"/>
        <column name="DESCRIPTION">descricaoCliente</column>
    </insert>

</changeSet>
```

Is this the expected behavior?  Bug of LiquiBase?  Or just me doing something wrong (the most likely) ?

Or is there any other way to import massive amount of data? But always using LiquiBase and/or Spring.

**EDIT2 :** My problem is that I'm unable to insert the  data into the second table with the correct foreign key

Comment: Added new alternative and test results

Comment: Could you clarify what the initial data is to be used for? Is it reference data that isn't typically going to change, but is required for the application to start? Will it only ever be inserted once?

Comment: It's initial data for the application to work, but I also need a solution that will work for any DB update, because there will be lots of updates that require lots of information being added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say that Liquibase is not the ideal tool for what you want to achieve. Liquibase is well-suited to managing the database structure, not the database's data.

If you still want to use Liquibase to manage the data, you have a couple of options (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144520/merging-values-from-db-using-liquibase-and-spring)) -

1. Record your insert statements as SQL, and refer to them from changelog.xml like this:

   `<sqlFile path="/path/to/file.sql"/>`
2. Use a [Custom Refactoring Class](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_refactoring_class) which you refer to from the changelog.xml like this:

   `<customChange class="com.example.YourJavaClass"
   csvFile="/path/to/file.csv"/>`

   YourJavaClass would read the records from the CSV file, and apply them to the database,  implementing this method:

   `void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException;`

Bear in mind, that once you have loaded this data via Liquibase, you shouldn't modify the data in the file, because those changes won't be re-applied. If you want to make changes to it, you would have to do it in subsequent changesets. So after a while you might end up with a lot of different CSV files/liquibase changesets, all operating on the same/similar data (this depends on how you are going to use this data - will it ever change once inserted?).

I would recommend looking at using [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) for managing your reference data. Its a tool primarily used in unit testing, but it is very mature, suitable for use in production I would say. You can store information in CSV or XML. I would suggest using a Spring 'InitializingBean' to load the dataset from the classpath and perform a DBUnit 'refresh' operation, which will, from the [docs](http://www.dbunit.org/apidocs/org/dbunit/operation/RefreshOperation.html):

> This operation literally refreshes dataset contents into the database. This
>     means that data of existing rows is updated and non-existing row get
>     inserted. Any rows which exist in the database but not in dataset stay
>     unaffected.

This way, you can keep your reference data in one place, and add to it over time so that there is only one source of the information, and it isn't split across multiple Liquibase changesets. Keeping your DBUnit datasets in version control would provide trace-ability, and as a bonus, DBUnit datasets are portable across databases, and can manage things like insert order to prevent foreign key violations for you.

Comment: I agree that DBUnit is a good approach for a Java+UnitTest approach to loading data. Unfortunately it won't scale if the requirements are for "massive" amounts of data.

Comment: I use DBUnit in integration tests to load a 4MB dataset spanning > 100 tables, and it takes < 1s against HSQLDB and 10s against MySQL. I doubt that Liquibase would be able to load the data much faster, because at the end of the day it is also using JDBC.

The OP is looking for a solution "always using LiquiBase and/or Spring", though I agree that for > 1GB, native tools would be better.

Comment: My problem is that I'm unable to insert the foreign keys in my table (and for what I found DBUnit has the same problem), and the solution for both cases looks like this: insert a record into the table with a fake FK, then update its FK to the correct one. PS: My initial import file is around 200MB, and my futures updates will be around 50MB

Comment: You shouldn't have problems "inserting" fk's with DBUnit as it supports that as long as your database allows it. I have had issues with fk's using CLEAN_INSERT. [See my post for a possible work-around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214949/dbunit-sybase-unable-to-clean-insert). So the issue there was with "deleting", not "inserting".

Comment: My problem is that I need to insert in a "single commit" two different tables where the second one needs to add a foreign key to the first

Comment: Do you have circular foreign keys? If so, then don't think that DBUnit uas much support for that. It would be wise to refactor them out if at all possible...maybe you could post more information about the error you are getting?

Comment: My problem is that the client table as a FK to the Entity table and I'm unable to insert the two transactions in a "single commit". I don't want to use DBUnit because I already have to much extra packages for a "simple" thing. So currently I'm using standard SQL inside a LiquiBase changelog file

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your target database. If you are using **Sybase** or **MSSQL** server then you can use the [BCP tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) that comes along with your installed client+driver. It is the fastest way of moving large amounts of data in/out of these databases.

Googling around I also found these links...

Oracle has the [SQL*LOADER](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ) tool

MySQL has the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://www.ben90.com/2011/06/import-bcp-output-file-into-mysql-database/) command

I would expect each database vendor to supply a tool of some description for bulk loading of data.

Comment: Where does LiquiBase or Spring come in play in that answer?

Comment: I was answering your statement at the end of your question ..."Or is there any other way to import massive amount of data?". I figured you weren't getting any joy with any answers at all and this might be of use.

Comment: Ah, ok. My other way question all involved LiquiBase and/or Spring ;)
Just edited the original post to clarify it